# Process, JoinableQueue process safety

Tags: windows, python-2.7, process, queue, multiprocessing

Recently I got into multiprocessing in Python. This code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from Queue import Empty
from multiprocessing import Process, JoinableQueue

def _print():
    while True:
        try:
            p = q.get(True, 3)
        except Empty:
            return
        else:
            print "Got: " + p 
            q.task_done()
    return

def _generate():
    pw = bytearray(1);
    for pw[0] in range(ord('a'), ord('z') + 1):
        q.put(pw)
        print "Put: " + pw

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = JoinableQueue()

    t = Process(target=_generate)
    t.start()

    t = Process(target=_print)
    t.start()

    q.join()
```

Gives me this output:

```
Put: a
... # Correct order a-z and no duplicates
Put: z
Got: a
Got: b
Got: d
Got: d
... # Missing characters and duplicates
Got: z
```

According to the documentation and other threads here on SO I couldn't manage to figure out where is the process safety issue in the above code.

I have a feeling that I am missing something trivial. Can anyone spot the issue? Is there a way to make this safe, i.e the output will correctly put and get every character and once only?

I am using Python 2.7 on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by using `itertools` to generate the characters.
The issue apparently seems to be caused by python's handling of `bytearray`.